# Tela de splash com Phonegap

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

Não estou conseguindo utilizar o plugin `splash-screen`

[image: erro de splash]

Ele fica nesta tela e não sai disso.

Meu config.xml esta como foi criado sem alterações.

Comment: Qual tipo de mobile esta testando? android ou ios?

Comment: Se for ios, veja se alguma dessas respostas pode te ajudar

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=splash+phonegap

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio é Android. Ele aparece a tela de login que deveria e rapidamente vai pra essa tela da imagem.